# How to update syntax error checking of Typescript 1.6 manually in Webstorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Typescript 1.6 have Recently released on development preview version, There are several new features I would like to use such as abstract classes ,generator function in Webstorm. I configured the Typescript compiler in Preferences/Typescript point to binary folder of Typescript 1.6 built by Jake, But an error highlight still occurred even though compiling has no any errors

How to update syntax error checking of Typescript 1.6 manually in Webstorm?

Comment: Please follow this issue on TypeScript 1.6 support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17412

Answer (score 2):

Can't. Not officially anyways. Recommend using unstable channel to get it when it happens.